# Python Module not found error when using as Package

Tags: python

I have two python files namely `abc.py` and `xyz.py`

`abc.py` contains two `function` viz `func_1()` and `func_2()`

My directory structure is as follows

```
db_ops /
   __init__.py
  abc.py
  xyz.py
```

Now in `xyz.py` I have the following import method

```
from db_ops.abc import func_1
```

When I run `xyz.py` I am getting error as

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db_ops'
```

Am I missing out anything?

P.S. I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a package for this, since all your code is in the same directory.

Simply use `from abc import func_1` since xyz and abc are in the same directory

Comment: The same erroer

Comment: Just to confirm, your code is ```from abc import func_1``` in a file called ```xyz.py``` and theres another file called ```abc.py``` in the same directory. How could you be getting an error ```No module named 'db_ops'``` if your code doesn't mention ```db_ops```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the answer for the problem I was facing.
We need to add the `dir path` where `abc.py` and `xyz.py` are located.

Assuming we have the broad dir structure as follows

```
etl_works/
db_ops 
__init__.py/
 __init__.py
 abc.py
 xyz.py
```

And `etl_works` directory is as follows

```
'D:/my_py/etl_works'
```

Then we need to add the above to the `sys.path` i.e.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('D:/my_py/etl_works')
```

And then we can use `import db_ops` or `from db_ops import abc`

**Caveat:**

The above method is not a permanent solution. Every time we close the program or kernel, the `path.append` method gets reversed. To circumvent this, we simply add the above dir path to PYTHONPATH (on in Windows 10 system, we add the path to Environment and system properties)

Hope this helps to any newbies like me!!